# Trying to convert HSV image to Black and white [opencv]

Tags: python, opencv, pixel, hsv

I have a skin detection code that works nicely to separate out skin pixels from the background of a **HSV** image.

[image]

Now, I want to convert the image on right to Black and white. 
**My logic** is to check all non-black pixels and change their Saturation value to 0 and Intensity value to 255.

So essentially, pixels would be [0-255,0,255]. I am using python with opencv.

```
h,b = skin.shape[:2]    

    for i in xrange(h):
        for j in xrange(b):
            # check if it is a non-black pixel
            if skin[i][j][2]>0:
                # set non-black pixel intensity to full
                skin[i][j][2]=255
                # set saturation zero
                skin[i][j][1]=0
```

But it produces this output -

[image]

How can I convert those ***pink pixels to white***??

Comment: You are referencing `skin[i][j][2]` (Value) twice - you never change Hue or Saturation. Your code might be clearer with a line e.g. `HUE, SAT, VAL = range(3)`, then it's harder to make mistakes like that.

Comment: I don't know opencv, but shouldn't you be doing `skin[i][j][1]=0` to set the saturation to 0?

Comment: @PM2Ring yes, thanks. I edited that bit. I had changed my code a little before I posted and forgot to recheck it.

Comment: Check out the answer posted ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are basically looking for [Thresholding](http://opencv-python-tutroals.readthedocs.org/en/latest/py_tutorials/py_imgproc/py_thresholding/py_thresholding.html), basically the concept is selecting a threshold value and any pixel value (grayscale) greater than threshold is set to be white and black otherwise. `OpenCV` has some beautiful inbuilt methods to do the same but it is really simple code:

```
skin = #Initialize this variable with the image produced after separating the skin pixels from the image.

bw_image = cv2.cvtColor(skin, cv2.HSV2GRAY)

new_image = bw_image[:]

threshold = 1 
 #This value is set to 1 because We want to separate out the pixel values which are purely BLACK whose grayscale value is constant (0)
```

Now we simply iterate over the image and substitute the values accordingly.

```
h,b = skin.shape[:2]    

for i in xrange(h):
    for j in xrange(b):
        if bw_image[i][j] > threshold:
            new_image[i][j] = 255 #Setting the skin tone to be White
        else:
            new_image[i][j] = 0 #else setting it to zero.
```

Comment: Thanks! Although, in my opencv version (2.4.5) it can't find cv2.HSV2GRAY. So I changed to BGR and then to grayscale.